# Can I Remove comment_body on my Node

Tags: nodes

Is it safe to remove this when I create a custom node?  It is not relevant to what I am doing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,
It's safe to remove comment body from the type of node you have created.
One may turn off the comments settings from content-type settings.